# Could I use an external ssd connected to router via usb 3 and to computer va SMB as my plex server?

Tags: macos, ssd, smb, plex, asus

I have an external SSD attached via USB 3 to my router, an ASUS RT-AC series.

I don't have any of the special file sharing services offered by 'Asuswrt' on at all, no Aicloud or anything, just the local file share through SMB.

It connects fine to my Mac Mini mid 2011 (upgraded) and I can play media off of it nicely.

Question is, does anybody use SMB specifically with macOS for their Plex Server?

Or anyone think of a reason I *shouldn't?*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason this cannot or will not work, just be aware that all the time Plex Server is running you must have the library available or Plex will simply empty its library and re-add it when the share comes back.

By the looks of it Plex prefers to have the media locally, but most operating systems allow you to "map" SMB shares into your local system which will fill that requirement.

Plex even has a guide [Mounting Network Resources](https://support.plex.tv/articles/201122318-mounting-network-resources/) which describes the process of mounting the share and setting it to appear when your machine logs in.

After that it is as simple as adding a new library in Plex and pointing it at the location of your files. The files will then be indexed and shared.